# How to save locally and retrieve files using Codename One and CN1 Filechooser?

Tags: codenameone

I have studied the [Files, Storage and Networking](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) instructions on the Codename One website. I am trying to

1. **save** files selected by the Codename One filechooser to the device (simulator, Android, iPhone)
2. **retrieve** the files saved locally in whatever device they got saved on.

Here is the code I used:

```
 final Button getFileChooser = new Button("Get file chooser");
    getFileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            if (FileChooser.isAvailable()) {
                FileChooser.showOpenDialog(".pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png", e2-> {
                    String file = (String)e2.getSource();
                    if (file == null) {
                        hi.add("No file was selected");
                        hi.revalidate();
                    } else {
                        String extension = null;
                        if (file.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) {
                            extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
                            ToastBar.showMessage("1: " + file, FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK);
                            rawFilename.setText("raw: " + file);
                            //java.util.List<String> filepathParsed = StringUtil.tokenize(file, "[/.]");
                            StringBuilder hi = new StringBuilder(file);
                            if (file.startsWith("file://"))
                                hi.delete(0, 7);
                            int lastIndexPeriod = hi.toString().lastIndexOf(".");
                            Log.p(hi.toString());
                            String ext = hi.toString().substring(lastIndexPeriod);
                            String hmore = hi.toString().substring(0, lastIndexPeriod -1);

                            String hi2 = hmore +/* "/file" +*/ ext;/*hi;*/
                            Log.p("hi2 = " + hi2);
                            secondFilename.setText("2nd: " + hi2);
                            //secondFilename.setText((String)evt.getSource());
                            try {
                                saveFileToDevice(file, ext);
                            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                                e.getMessage();
                            }
                            //sendFileViaEmail(hi2, file);


                        } else {
                            ToastBar.showMessage("2: " + file + " " + extension, FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK);
                        }
                    }
                    hi.revalidate();
                });
            }
        }
    });

 protected void saveFileToDevice(String hi, String ext) throws URISyntaxException{
    URI uri = new URI(hi);
    String path = uri.getPath();
    Log.p("uri path: " + uri.getPath() + " ; scheme: " + uri.getScheme());
    /*if (path.contains("..jpg")) {
        int indexLastPeriodBeforeExt = path.lastIndexOf(".");
        path = path.substring(0, indexLastPeriodBeforeExt) + path.substring(indexLastPeriodBeforeExt+ 1);
        Log.p("new path: " + path);

    }*/
    if (Display.getInstance().getPlatformName().equals("and"))
        path = "file://" +path;
    String home = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
    char sep = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getFileSystemSeparator();
    String userDir = home + sep + "myapp";
    /*if (hi.startsWith("file://")) {
        hi = hi.substring(7);
    }*/
    int index = hi.lastIndexOf("/");
    hi = hi.substring(index + 1);
    Log.p("hi after substring 7: " + hi);
    FileSystemStorage.getInstance().mkdir(userDir);
    String fPath = userDir + sep + hi ;
  /*  if (hi.contains("..jpg")) {
        int indexLastPeriodBeforeExt = hi.lastIndexOf(".");
        hi = hi.substring(0, indexLastPeriodBeforeExt) + hi.substring(indexLastPeriodBeforeExt+ 1);
        Log.p("new hi: " + hi);
    }*/

        Log.p("does it exist? " + FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(userDir));
        String imageFile = userDir + sep + hi;
         String[] roots = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots();
            if (roots.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++)
                    Log.p("roots" + i + " " + roots[i]);
            }
            try {
                String[] files = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().listFiles(userDir);
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    Log.p(i + " " + files[i]);
                    //secondName = files[files.length-1];
                    Log.p("secondname: " + secondName);
                }
                sendFileViaEmail(imageFile, ".jpg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

protected void sendFileViaEmail(String hi2, String file) {
    Message m = new Message("Test message");
    //m.getAttachments().put(file, "image/jpeg");
    m.setAttachment(hi2);
    m.setAttachmentMimeType(Message.MIME_IMAGE_JPG);
    //m.setMimeType(Message.MIME_IMAGE_JPG);
    //m.getAttachments().put(imageAttachmentUri, "image/png");
    Display.getInstance().sendMessage(new String[] {"myemail@example.com"}, "test message cn1", m);
}
```

I added the `getFileChooser` button to my Form after importing the [cn1-filechooser library](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-filechooser) to my project and refreshed libs. The filechooser works -- I tried it on the simulator, Android device and iPhone.

My issue is here:

`String file` retrieves what looks like a URI. I tried to convert the URI to a File and when I run the following code to see that the files are stored I see them in my logs, although in a funny order, which I'm ok with.

```
 String[] files = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().listFiles(userDir);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                Log.p(i + " " + files[i]);
                //secondName = files[files.length-1];
                Log.p("secondname: " + secondName);
            }
```

**How do retrieve a valid, uncorrupted version of this file from `FileSystemStorage`? Am I storing it wrong?** Whenever I run the method to send the file via email, it opens Outlook (on my Desktop) but no files is attached? (I assume that the file is invalid/corrupted when trying to retrieve it from `FileSytemStorage` -- please help.) I hardcoded `.jpg` as MIME-type but only as a test; my goal is to be able to save/restore .pdf, .png, .jpg, and.jpeg files.

Thanks!

**EDIT: ** This seems to show that the file was actually saved to my app's storage. How do I stream the content of the file be copied/uploaded or emailed from my app?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile phones don't allow that. They don't have a file system like desktops have. So file chooser really launches a tool to help you pick a file from a different app, this file is then copied to your local app sandbox where you can get access to the content of the app.

Naturally this won't work for save as it would mean you could potentially corrupt a file within another application so you are restricted from writing to the directories of other applications installed or even knowing which applications are installed and where...

To transfer a file to a different app you have the share intent which you can use via the share button or the low level API's in display. This allows you to send an image to whatsapp or similar functionality that makes sense in a mobile phone.

Comment: Thanks. By intents do you mean intents like `ACTION_VIEW` and `ACTION_SEND` in Android, is that what you mean? How do you use the share intent you mentioned in Cn1?  I want to save the selected file to my app directory so I can retrieve it later to upload or email later. Is that possible?

Comment: It maps to that on Android but generally it's just `Display.share` or the `ShareButton` class. You can't retrieve it by email since there isn't really a concept of your app directory for most OS's. Open gmail on iOS and Android then click attach, you will see that what you get isn't exactly a file picker dialog. If email is all you care about you can use the send message API which allows you to add attachments and will launch the OS email client with given attachment in place...

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering how to stream the content of the file be uploaded or emailed from my app? It that possible?

Comment: Attachment needs a physical file that's already written and stored as you will be switching to a different app to complete the process and mobile OS's enforce a very strong app isolation policy for security

Comment: Thanks, but didn&#39;t you write that &quot;file is then copied to your local app sandbox where you can get access to the content of the app&quot;? Can't I get access to its contents in my app?

Comment: It can't. We essentially use OS native API's to "export" the file to a special space. We hide some of those complexities to create a seamless API

Comment: Where would that be? If the file is exported to someplace in the app, can't I save the file and then upload it from within my app?

Comment: You do save the file somewhere and we seamlessly allow it to attach to an email. You can save it to the app home directory, I think there is a sample in the javadoc.

Comment: I was able to save it to the app under `files` dir, and view it when debugging an Android version in Android Studio so I know it saved correctly. 2 issues though: 1) After copy-pasting the path and hardcoding it into my MultipartRequest's `addData` method, it comes up empty or corrupted. Can you explain what I need to do to upload it? 2) When I save it under a new dir under files (and I remembered to use `mkdir`), a corrupted version of the file gets saved in that dir and a valid file opens under `files`. Please help.

Comment: I didn't understand that. Notice that for multipart to work you need to read a multipart upload on the server side and not just save the content of the request as it includes separator etc.